# ASP .NET MVC 5 - How to add form model inside Ajax.ActionLink?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on the table paging, where each page calls the controller to get part of the data, then return the partial view and update it into HTML table.

Here's my controller look like:

```cs
public ActionResult SearchData(FormModel model, int? page)
{
    /*Codes to get data from DB*/
    return PartialView("_DataTable", model);
}
```

The form input is something like this:

```cs
@model Project.ViewModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("SearchData", "Player", new AjaxOptions 
    { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "data-table", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FormModel.Username)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FormModel.Username, new { placeholder = "[Username]" })
    
    @*And some more input, all are in FormModel class.*@
}

<div id="data-table">
   @Html.Partial("_DataTable")
</div>
```

The way I generate the page is as follows:

```cs
for (var pageNum = Model.PlayerList.Pager.StartPage; pageNum <= Model.PlayerList.Pager.EndPage; pageNum++)
{
   if (pageNum == Model.PlayerList.Pager.CurrentPage)
   {
       <td><span>@pageNum</span></td>
   }
   else
   {
       <td>
           @Ajax.ActionLink(pageNum.ToString(), "SearchData", new {page = pageNum}, new AjaxOptions
           {
               HttpMethod = "GET",
               InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
               UpdateTargetId = "data-table"
           })
       </td>
   }
}
```

I can only pass in the `page` value, is it possible to include the form input `Model` into `Ajax.ActionLink`? Something like this:

```cs
new {model = Model.FormModel, page = pageNum}
```

I tried the method above, but didn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came out with another solution. I put the form model inside `TempData` just before the controller returns the partial view. At the beginning of the controller, I check if the page value is null, the form input should take from `TempData` instead. This way, we only pass in the page value since the form input model should always the same, using `Ajax.ActionLink` as I posted on the question.

Here's the code:

```cs
public ActionResult SearchData(FormModel model, int? page)
{
   if (page != null)
   {
      model = TempData["FormModel"] as FormModel ?? new FormModel();
   }

   /*Codes to get data from DB*/
   
   TempData["FormModel"] = model;
   return PartialView("_DataTable", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need add properties of FormModel like this

`new {Username="some username",page = pageNum}`

Comment: Yeah, but there are 18 form inputs I need to pass in, I need simpler way to add them all in one shot, instead of adding one by one.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this and change fields names and values as your model

**note**: unfortunately, you should send each value one by one, but not the whole model

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(pageNum.ToString(), "SearchData",
    new
    {
        FielNameInModel1= Model.FieldNameInModel,
        FielNameInModel2 = "xyz",
        FielNameInModel3 = 5,
        FielNameInModel4 = pageNum.ToString(),
    },
    new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, UpdateTargetId = "AllProjectsDiv", OnComplete = "AjaxFormCompleted" }
, new { @class = "className") })
```